# Is there a way to stop receiving data after service request via volley?

Tags: android, android-volley

My intention is to stop receiving data from the server after the user has moved away from the activity which has made the service request. The motivation is to reduce the unnecessary bandwidth consumption as the user has navigated away from the activity and hence, the data is no longer required.

As far as I know, in Volley, it is only possible to cancel a request if it's in the request queue and not if it has already been sent.

So, is there any way to refuse the data being sent to the phone from the server or else, change the priority of the data acceptance to a lower level?

Comment: If a request is been made , response will come , but you can create a manager for your responses , As you want to send response to activity or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel the `Volley Request` which means you will not receive the response. When you are initiating `Volley Request` the request tag and cancel it via tag.

Hope this helps.